# Require advice on Time Series Database solution that fits with Apache Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, opentsdb, druid, bigdata

For example, lets say I wish to analyze a months worth of company data for trends. I plan on doing regression analysis and classification using an MLP.

A months worth of data has  ~10 billion data points (rows).
There are 30 dimensions to the data.
12 features are numeric (integer or float; continuous).
The rest are categoric (integer or string).

Currently the data is stored in flat files (CSV) and is processed and delivered in batches. Data analysis is carried out in R.

I want to:

1. change this to **stream** processed (rather than batch process).
2. offload the computation to a **Spark cluster**
3. house the data in a **time-series database** to facilitate easy read/write and query. 
   In addition, I want the cluster to be able to query data from the database when loading the data into memory.

I have an *Apache Kafka* system that can publish the feed for the processed input data. I can write a Go module to interface this into the database (via CURL, or a Go API if it exists). 
There is already a development Spark cluster available to work with (assume that it can be scaled as necessary, if and when required).

But I'm stuck on the choice of database. There are many solutions (here is a non-exhaustive [list](http://www.erol.si/2015/01/the-complete-list-of-all-timeseries-databases-for-your-iot-project/)) but I'm looking at *OpenTSDB*, *Druid* and *Axibase Time Series Database*. 
Other time-series databases which I have looked at briefly, seem more as if they were optimised for handling metric data. (I have looked at InfluxDB, RiakTS and Prometheus)

> Spark runs on Hadoop, Mesos, standalone, or in the cloud. It can
>   access diverse data sources including HDFS, Cassandra, HBase, and S3. - *Apache Spark Website*

In addition, the time-series database should store that data in a fashion that **exposes it directly to Spark** (as this is time-series data, it should be *immutable and therefore satisfies the requirements of an RDD* - therefore, it can be loaded natively by Spark into the cluster). 
Once the data (or data with dimensionality reduced by dropping categoric elements) is loaded, using sparklyr (a R interface for Spark) and Spark's machine learning library (MLib, [this cheatsheet](http://spark.rstudio.com/images/sparklyr-cheatsheet.pdf) provides a quick overview of the functionality), regression and classification model can be developed and experimented with.

So, my questions:

1. Does this seem like a reasonable approach to working with big data?
2. Is my choice of database solutions correct? (I am set on working with columnar store and time-series database, please do not recommend SQL/Relational DBMS)
3. If you have prior experience working with data analysis on clusters, from both an analytics and systems point of view (as I am doing both), do you have any advice/tips/tricks?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Almost all the nosql databases are fit for time-series data. Explore Cassandra and mango and decide which fits to your need.

Comment: It's an interesting use case. We'd be happy to provide free technical support for your project.  Feel free to reach out to us via an email address listed on http://axibase.com/customer-support/

Comment: we have faced the same situation, could you please share some tips if you have found a way to handle this use case.

Comment: It was deemed that ElasticSearch was fit for purpose. Logstash was used to interface to the Kafka brokers and carried out appropriate data sanitisation. Spark has modules that can connect and query data from Elastic Search.

I was only involved in the development of the a proof of concept so I cannot provide further information with reference to scalability. SparklyR was used to connect and query the data but it may be worth investigating but that was just because I wanted a R front end.